# iOS FB-sdk 3.1 - login with different username

Tags: ios, sdk, facebook-login

I added test-users to my FB-app on FB and now I want to login to FB from my iPHone-app using the test user's credentials.
But I used my own username already and now FB only presents the «allow permissions» screen and always skips the login screen.

How do I tell my app to forget previous logins and use new credentials?

[Edit]

This is on the simulator, not an actual device...

Comment: You rather mean `iOS Facebook client library 3.1`, right? The iOS 3.1 SDK was good 3 years ago, but now we have version 6 of the OS and nobody cares about 3.1 anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the simulator, go to Settings -> Safari -> clear cookies and data.

This works because on the simulator you can't install the fb app so single-sign-on is always performed via mobile safari (when fb is not configured via ios6 which it sounds like it isn't based on your described behavior)

Comment: Thanks! Additionally, I had to delete the app, too. Just resetting Safari didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution for your case:
iOS simulator->Reset content and settings: that will clean up your FB tokens on the simulators.